# Hibernate Session expires in Wizard

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm building a wizard using hibernate. I want to initialize the session at the beginning of the wizard and commit it at the end of the wizard. The wizard consist of several pages and I'd like to continue building the object from one page to the next. My object is complex consisting of many joins.

Everything I've tried thus far has failed, I don't want to get real id's until I'm ready to commit. Does anybody know how to do this. If so, could you provide a code sample.

Comment: What do you mean the session expires?  Hibernate sessions do not expire.  Are you talking about the JDBC connection or the transaction?

Comment: Hibernate is very new to me so perhaps I'm using the wrong terminology, when the page reloads, I lose all my data. I don't know how to get it back from the session. There is no id yet since it hasn't been saved.

Comment: Is the session object going out of context and thus disposing?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "going out of context".